# Pandas: Apply a function that returns the division between two rows, for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is grouped by the indexes 'age group' and 'churn'

| age group | churn | salary | debt | investments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21-30 | 0 | 5000 | 3000 | 2500 |
| 21-30 | 1 | 4000 | 2000 | 5000 |
| 31-40 | 0 | 6000 | 2500 | 1000 |
| 31-40 | 1 | 2000 | 2000 | 1000 |

I'd like create a new dataframe that returns the division between column[churn==1] / column[churn==0] for each numeric column

Desired dataframe:

| age group | variation_salary | variation_debt | variation_investments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21-30 | 0.8 | 0.66 | 2 |
| 31-40 | 0.33 | 0.8 | 1 |

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `age group` again, select the relevant columns, and then use [`.last()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) to get the entry corresponding to `churn==1` within the group and [`.first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) to get the entry corresponding to `churn==0` within the group.  Then, use them for division:

```
g = df.groupby('age group')[['salary', 'debt', 'investments']]

g.last() / g.first()
```

**Result:**

```
             salary      debt  investments
age group                                 
21-30      0.800000  0.666667          2.0
31-40      0.333333  0.800000          1.0
```

**Another approach**: you can also filter by `churn==1` and `churn==0` before grouping, as follows:

```
g1 = df.loc[df['churn']==1].groupby('age group')[['salary', 'debt', 'investments']].first()

g0 = df.loc[df['churn']==0].groupby('age group')[['salary', 'debt', 'investments']].first()

g1 / g0
```

**Result:**

```
             salary      debt  investments
age group                                 
21-30      0.800000  0.666667          2.0
31-40      0.333333  0.800000          1.0
```

We can further fine-tune to your desired layout, as follows:

```
df_out = ((g.last() / g.first())
              .add_prefix('variation_')
              .reset_index()
         )
```

Or, for the alternative approach, use:

```
df_out = ((g1 / g0)
              .add_prefix('variation_')
              .reset_index()
         )
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

  age group  variation_salary  variation_debt  variation_investments
0     21-30          0.800000        0.666667                    2.0
1     31-40          0.333333        0.800000                    1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

When setting the age group and churn as index, you can then select subsets with [`.xs()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) and the age group index will ensure you’re dividing the same age groups with each other:

```
>>> df = df.set_index(['age group', 'churn'])
>>> df.xs(1, 'index', 'churn') / df.xs(0, 'index', 'churn')
             salary      debt  investments
age group                                 
21-30      0.800000  0.666667          2.0
31-40      0.333333  0.800000          1.0
```

You can then also call `.reset_index()` on the result.